# Roundabout conservation of energy and angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So I was doing a practice question which is as follows:

> A child weighing 30 kg running at 5 m s-1 jumps tangentially onto the outer edge of an initially stationary
>   roundabout of radius 2 m. The roundabout can be considered as having all its mass in the base which is made
>   of 5 cm thick iron of density 7900 kg m-3. What is the resulting angular velocity of the roundabout. Assume
>   no friction in the bearings. What is the centripetal force acting on the child? What constant torque would need
>   to be applied in order to bring the roundabout plus child to a stop in 5 seconds.

The solution asks me to use conservation of angular momentum, but I chose to use conservation of energy. However I found the two answers to be different and am confused as to why.

My solution is as follows:
$$
K.E_{initial} = \frac{1}{2}m_{child}*v_{child}  ^2 
$$

And hence 
$$
K.E_{final} = \frac{1}{2}I_{total}\omega^2 = \frac{1}{2}(I_{roundabout}+I_{child})\omega^2
$$

Equating the two equations together we arrive at
$$
m_{child}v_{child}^2 = I_{total}\omega^2
$$

However, this vastly differs from the equation we arrive at with conservation of angular momentum, which is
$$
m_{child}v_{child}r = I\omega
$$
Substituting in the numbers, the $\omega$ are out by a factor of 10. What quantity have I forgotten about when performing this calculation?

Comment: I see some people voting to close this question, but it seems to me this is a clear example of a conceptual homework question. It's presenting two methods of getting to a solution and asking why they differ.

Comment: @DavidZ: seems to me we close those all the time for the 'check my work' aspect that the [community also doesn't like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).)

Comment: @KyleKanos Not all the time that I've seen. Or if we do, we shouldn't. In any case, the important point is that I'm quite sure this is not a check-my-work question and that it should not be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanical energy isn't conserved in this case. The child loses some energy attaching themselves to the roundabout, perhaps through the friction of their shoes on the surface.

The result for final angular speed using conservation of angular momentum looks like this:
$$\omega_f = \frac{2mv_0}{R(2m+M)} \to \omega_f^{\,2} = \left(\frac{2mv_0}{R(2m+M)}\right)^2$$

And the same result using conservation of kinetic energy looks like this:
$$\omega_f^{\,2} = \frac{2mv_0^{\,2}}{R^2(2m+M)}$$

If we set these two results equal to each other, we get this expression as a condition for their equality:
$$\left(\frac{2mv_0}{R(2m+M)}\right)\left(\frac{2mv_0}{R(2m+M)} - \frac{v_0}{R}\right) = 0$$

This can only be satisfied if one of $m$, $M$, or $v_0$ are set to zero. Since we don't have any of those, we have to conclude that mechanical energy is not conserved.

A last thought: maybe you've done collision problems to learn about conservation of translational/linear momentum. If you remember, an inelastic collision is one where momentum is conserved, but mechanical energy is not. Many practice problems for inelastic collisions involve two objects sticking together $-$ exactly what we have here.